# How to extract a positive definite submatrix from a PSD matrix?

Tags: matrices

Let $M$ be a real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix s.t. there is only one zero eigenvalue.

**Question:** Is it true that there is a unique principal submatrix that is positive definite? If so, how to determine this submatrix?

**First trial:** Let the eigenvector corresponding to the zero eigenvalue be $v$. We can represent $M$ as
\begin{equation}M=Q'DQ,\tag{*}\end{equation} 
where $Q'Q=I$ and $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Suppose for certainty that the last element of D is equal to $0$, i.e., $d_{nn}=0$. This means that the last column of $Q$ is equal to $v$.

Now let's write $D=\begin{bmatrix}D_1& 0\\0& 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $Q=\begin{bmatrix}\tilde Q& q_1\\q_2'& x\end{bmatrix}$, where $D_1$ is a PD diagonal matrix, $\tilde Q$ is an $[n-1,n-1]$ matrix, $q_1$ and $q_2$ are vectors, and $x$ is a scalar.

With this, we rewrite (*) as
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}\tilde Q'& q_2\\q_1'& x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}D_1& 0\\0& 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\tilde Q& q_1\\q_2'& x\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\tilde Q'D_1& 0\\q_1'D_1& 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\tilde Q& q_1\\q_2'& x\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\tilde Q'D_1\tilde Q& \tilde Q'D_1q_1\\q_1'D_1\tilde Q& q_1'D_1q_1\end{bmatrix}$$

Here, $\tilde Q'D_1\tilde Q$ is the $(n,n)$-principal submatrix of $M$, which is positive definite **if** $\tilde Q$ is non-singular. Thus the problem boils down to deternining non-singular principal submatrices of $Q$. However, I'm not sure is this makes the problem any simpler..

**Solution (?):** The number of PD principal submatrices id equal to the number of non-zero elements in the eigenvector $v$. If $v_i\neq 0$, $M[i]$ is PD.

I will post the proof in a day or so.

Comment: You can extract principal submatrices using "elimination matrices"

Comment: @Bertrand, I know how to extract submatrices. The question is rather which one is to extract?

Answer (score 1):

This result stated for instance by Moschini may be useful:

Lemma. Let $S$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix that satisfies $Sp = 0$, where $p \ne 0$, and let $\tilde{S}$ be an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix obtained from $S$ by deleting any one row and the corresponding column. Then a necessary and sufficient condition
for $S$ to be negative semidefinite is that $\tilde{S}$ is negative semidefinite.

Moschini, G., 1999, "Imposing Local Curvature Conditions in Flexible Demand Systems," Journal of Business & Economic Statistics, 17, 487-490.

Comment: Shouldn't it read: "... is that $\tilde S$ is negative definite"? Otherwise I'm not sure that this statement is true. Anyway, this does not solve my problem.

Comment: It is negative semidefinite, and not negative definite. The reason is clear in the proof. The lemma does not apply to diagonal matrices, as diagonal matrices do not satisfy $Sp = 0$ for $p \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counter-example to your conjecture: the matrix
$$
M=\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & -1 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 2 & -1 \\ 
-1 & -1 & 2
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
is positive semi-definite and has rank $2$, but any matrix extracted by
eliminating the $i^{th}$ row and column is positive definite.

Comment: You are right. I've already recognized that. Please see the last lines in my answer. There, $v$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the zero eigenvalue. That result agrees with your observation: $v=[1,1,1]$ hence, all principal submatrices will be PD.